# Type Error when trying to move Turtle in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm try to move to turtle to random places to draw a star but when I run the code I get :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "so_quick_run.py", line 36,
>   in
>
> ```
> main()   File "so_quick_run.py", line 34, in main
> move()   File "so_quick_run.py", line 28, in move
> alex.goto(rng(), rng())   File
> ```
>
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py",
>   line 1689, in goto
>       self._goto(Vec2D(*x)) TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not NoneType

I think I'm getting this problem from using an RNG from my turtle's goto command.

```
#Import turtle
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Turtle()

#Turtle Setting
alex.speed(10)
alex.color("yellow")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.screensize(600,600)

#Drawing star
def star(alex):
  for x in range(5):
      alex.pendown()
      alex.forward(50)
      alex.right(144)
      alex.penup()

#Randon Number Generator
import random
def rng():
  for i in range(1):
    random.randint(-250,250)

#Moving turtle
def move():
    alex.penup()
    alex.goto(rng(), rng())
    alex.pendown()

#Main funaton
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        move()
        star(alex)
main()

#Ending the loop
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message. You do not even have a `*` in the code that you posted. Also, your function `rng()` does not return anything.

Comment: I ran OP's code and found that the error he mentions is somewhere from inside the library. Edited the question to add the stack trace, if it helps someone. (in case, calling function has error)

Comment: And why is there a loop in `rng()`?

Comment: @Tushar: The error is clear. He uses `alex.goto(rng(), rng())`, but the result of `rng()` is `None` (as @DYZ mentioned). So the call is `alex.goto(None, None)` and `None` is not a valid value for those parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DYZ mentioned, you're not returning anything in `rng()` just return the random number that you generate:

```
#Randon Number Generator
import random
def rng():
    for i in range(1):
        return random.randint(-250,250)
```

Comment: @RickyKim: Why did you leave the loop in there? Do you see any usage for that (other then wasting computing time)?

Comment: @Matthias I thought maybe OP wanted to use the loop for something? If not, yes, the loop should be removed.